# Programs appear in different order on taskbar every time I start my PC

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have some programs namely Skype and IMVU which I have set to "Run On Startup" along with other programs like IE, Firefox, Google. However the order of the programs appearing on my Taskbar keeps switching from time to time?

Is that possible to happen or my PC has some virus because that never happened to me before.  And is there a way i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, post the windows version you are using.

Second, the possibility of it being a virus is very low, I would say, since there's no point for a virus to reproduce that pattern. If you need to give a program a fixed position on your taskbar, you can select the option "Fix the program on the taskbar", and then drag that item around.

Here's a gif i did to demonstrate:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am using windows 7. Thank you for the gif that helped a lot. But i mostly wanted to know if that happens in generally or is it just me?

Comment: @Costas programs appear on the taskbar based on how they are started. Given that there are 3 or 4 different ways to start a program at system run, and not every program starts at exactly the same speed when the computer boots, it is possible one program is finished starting before another while next time it is differently. This is what makes your programs appear random on your taskbar during startup.

Comment: Oh so its a normal behavior that it keeps switching their order around on the taskbar every time because sometimes it opens them on a different speed. I got it. Thank you very much for your help really appreciated. :)